# Test method call that returns a promise with mocha

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocha.js, sinon

I'm new to Mocha but I read they support promises now but I can't seem to find any documentation that solves my problem. I have an authenticate method that returns a promise. In my test I need to wait till that gets done in order to pass/fail it.

Here is my Authenticate factory:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('app.authentication').factory('authentication', authentication);

/* @ngInject */
function authentication($window, $q, $location, authenticationData, Session) {
    var authService = {
        authenticate: authenticate
    };

    return authService;

    function authenticate() {
        var token = authenticationData.getToken();
        var deferral = $q.defer();
        if (!Session.userId && token) {
            authenticationData.getUser(token).then(function(results) {
                Session.create(results.id, results.userName, results.role);
                deferral.resolve();
            });
        }
        else{
            deferral.resolve();
        }

        return deferral.promise;
    }.........
```

Here is my Test:

```
describe('authentication', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('app', specHelper.fakeLogger);
        specHelper.injector(function($q, authentication, authenticationData, Session) {});
    });

    beforeEach(function() {
        sinon.stub(authenticationData, 'getUser', function(token) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(mockData.getMockUser());
            return deferred.promise;
        });
    });

    describe('authenticate', function() {
        it('should create Session with userName of TestBob', function() {
            authentication.authenticate().then(function(){
                console.log('is this right?');
                expect(Session.userName).to.equal('TesaatBob');
            }, function(){console.log('asdfasdf');});
        });
    });
});
```

When I run this, the test passes because it never makes it inside the promise and never hits the expect. If I put "return authenication.authenticate ...." then it errors with a timeout.

Thank you

Comment: you need to accept a `done` parameter to your `it`, and then execute it when finished, just like any other asynchronous test.

Comment: @Kevin B, do you have an example?

Comment: http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code note the code toward the end of that portion, you could simply return the promise itself.

Comment: That gets me back to an error of timing out.
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) authentication authenticate should create Session with userName of TestBob FAILED
 timeout of 2000ms exceeded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular promises do not get resolved until the next digest cycle.

See http://brianmcd.com/2014/03/27/a-tip-for-angular-unit-tests-with-promises.html:

> One thing that you'll quickly run into when unit testing Angular
>   applications is the need to hand-crank the digest cycle in certain
>   situations (via scope.$apply() or scope.$digest()). Unfortunately, one
>   of those situations is promise resolution, which is not very obvious
>   to beginning Angular developers.

I believe adding a `$rootScope.$apply()` should resolve your issue and force the promise resolution without the need for an asynchronous test.